# Variable in python 3 regex using {x} .format(a), also including specified length {y,z}

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string-formatting

I am trying to get a variable into my Python regex and have found that using string formatting like `{0}` with `.format(variable)` works normally, but now I also want to specify the length of some parts of my regex, like so:

```
n = re.search(r"""(((\s|^)        # Start with either whitespace or start of line
                  {0})            # String 'item'
                  \d{5,7}         # 5-7 digits
                  \b)             # End with word border
                  """.format(item), text, re.VERBOSE)
```

I guess the regex then interprets the specification of length `{5,7}` as also being a reference to a variable, because I get the error message `Key error: '5,7'`.

I get it to work specifying the regex as a variable before sending it to `re.search(regex, text)`, but I want to comment the different parts of the regex - thus using the verbose format.

I also tried using `%s` and `% item` for the string formatting, but this gave me a syntax error:

```
    """, % item, transcription, re.VERBOSE)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Have I made any mistakes in my code or do I have to use some other way (if there is one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the braces that need to be preserved as literals (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)):

```
n = re.search(r"""(((\s|^)        # Start with either whitespace or start of line
                  {0})            # String 'item'
                  \d{{5,7}}       # 5-7 digits
                  \b)             # End with word border
                  """.format(item), text, re.VERBOSE)
```